# Kotlin Coroutines - Asynchronously consume a sequence

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm looking for a way to keep a Kotlin sequence that can produces values very quickly, from outpacing slower async consumers of its values.  In the following code, if the async `handleValue(it)` cannot keep up with the rate that the sequence is producing values, the rate imbalance leads to buffering of produced values, and eventual out-of-memory errors.

```
getSequence().map { async {
  handleValue(it)
}}
```

I believe this is a classic producer/consumer "back-pressure" situation, and I'm trying to understand how to use Kotlin coroutines to deal with it.

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Did you look at flows? They're intended for such purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my own reference, and to anyone else this may help, here's how I eventually solved this using Channels - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#channel-basics

A producer coroutine:

```
fun itemChannel() : ReceiveChannel<MyItem> {
    return produce {
        while (moreItems()) {
            send(nextItem())   // <-- suspend until next 'receive()'
        }
    }
}
```

And a function to run multiple consumer coroutines, each reading off that channel:

```
fun itemConsumers() {
    runBlocking {
        val channel = itemChannel()
        repeat(numberOfConsumers) {
            launch {
                var more = true
                while (more) {
                    try {
                        val item = channel.receive()
                        // do stuff with item here...
                    } catch (ex: ClosedReceiveChannelException) {
                        more = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the consumer receives off the channel within the coroutine, so the next `receive()` is not called until a consumer coroutine finishes handling the last item. This results in the desired back-pressure, as opposed to receiving from a sequence or flow in the main thread, and then passing the item into a coroutine to be consumed. In that scenario there is no back-pressure from the receiver, since the receive happens in a different coroutine than where the received item is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin [channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html) and [flows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html) offer buffering producer dispatched data until the consumer/collector is ready to consume it.

But Channels have some concerns that have been manipulated in Flows; for instance, they are considered hot streams:

- The producer starts for dispatching data whether or not there is an attached consumer; and this introduces resource leaks.
- As long as no consumer attached to the producer, the producer will stuck in suspending state

However Flows are cold streams; nothing will be produced until there is something to consume.

To handle your query with Flows:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    flow {
        // Producer
        for (item in getSequence()) emit(item)

    }.map { handleValue(it) }
        .buffer(10) // Optionally specify the buffer size
        .collect { // Collector
            
        }
}
```

Comment: I'd tried this with flows before as well, and could not figure out the exact code structure to make it go.  This answer pointed me in the right direction - thx :)

Comment: Glad to know. Do you still faces issues?

Comment: ya - I had originally marked this as the answer that solved my problem, but actually I realized that it hadn't. While a Flow can support backpressure from a single slow consumer, iterating the flow with 'async' removes that backpressure by rapidly consuming and buffering all values produced in Deferred objects. I eventually solved this with a Channel and launching many consumer coroutines that read from the channel from within the coroutine, so 'receive()' is only called when the consumer is ready.